# Asp.Net Thread.Sleep ignored by redirect

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I'm working on an Asp.Net application page. Once submit has been pressed a dialog box is triggered to show that processing is underway. One processing is complete on the server, the aim is to briefly show an updated dialog box, then redirect after a delay.

```
    void ProcessApplication()
    {
        var redirectUrl = "https://www.bbc.co.uk";

        // Simulate processing
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        // Application accepted
        //
        lnkRedirect.NavigateUrl = redirectUrl;

        // Change the dialog box.
        gcProcessing.Visible = false;
        gcRedirecting.Visible = true;
        upProgress.Update(); <== this is an Asp.Net update panel

        // A brief delay to allow user to read updated message
        // before redirecting.
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        Response.Redirect(redirectUrl); <== redirect happens immediately - NO DELAY!
    }
```

The first delay works, the second doesn't. Anyone got any ideas as to why and possibly how to fix it?

Comment: In what way are you observing that this "doesn't work"?  I would expect this server-side operation to have a total of 13 seconds of delay, followed by the redirect.  I suspect the issue here is that you're expecting the *client-side* UI to be updated in the middle of this server-side operation, which of course won't happen.  If you want to update the client and then have a separate delay, you need to return a page to the client and then delay/redirect in client-side code.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your quick response. Yes, you're correct that I am expecting a 13 second delay. If I remove the redirect I see the updated page; with the redirect in place, I get the 10 second delay but not the 3 second delay. Can you explain a little more, I'm a bit baffled.

Comment: As far as I'm aware I'm returning the page to the client through the partial postback (update panel)., this line: upProgress.Update();

Comment: I'd be curious to know more about the HTTP interaction you're seeing in your browser's debugging tools.  Is this a page-level request, or an AJAX request?  What is the timing on the request/response and what is the response?  Ultimately I think you're kind of chasing your tail here and need to take a step back and get a stronger handle on the overall goal.  Maybe there's something I'm missing in AJAX-enabled WebForms controls, but in general I would recommend moving logic like this client-side if the goal is to show the user a progress indicator and then redirect after some time.

Comment: The update is the proprietary Asp.Net update panel - so Ajax. I just extended the second delay to 10 seconds and timed the overall delay. It was 20 seconds. So it's not ignoring the delay, it's ignoring the postback - but only when the redirect is active. If I remove the redirect the updated page is shown as expected. Strange!!! The page has to wait for the server to return the redirect url, which is why it's done at this point.

Comment: This all sounds like expected behavior.  A request is made to the server, the server performs its operation, and a response is returned to the client.  That response can be a redirect, a page, data to update the current page, etc.  But ultimately there's only one response per request.

Comment: You seem to be operating under the impression that there's some sort of live connection between the server side and client side, and that UI-related commands on the server will immediately result in changes on the client side. That's now how web applications generally work. Instead, there is an HTTP request sent from the client to the server, the server processes the request and generates updated HTML which it sends to the client as part of the response.

Comment: If you want the UI to to update as part of processing, you'd need to send one request to the server to start the long running task. The server will need to enqueue that work as background task and immediately send a response that the request was received and is now processing in the background. The client side can then poll the server periodically to check for the status of the background task. Once it sees the background task is completed, you can then redirect or otherwise update the UI accordingly.

Comment: Or you can maintain a live connection to the server via web sockets (perhaps by using SignalR) to push state updates from server to client. Your usage of UpdatePanel and misunderstanding of how Web Forms works is confusing you and leading you down a bad path. That's one of the reasons why Web Forms isn't a good framework for modern development. UpdatePanel is often a source of confusion, and you're better off avoiding it.